# i get an error when i run this code

Tags: java, pdf, jar, apache-poi, docx

```
package demo;

import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*; 
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

public class DocxToPdf {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    try
        {
            String inputFile = "F:\\MY WORK\\CollectionPractice\\WebContent\\APCR1.docx";
            String outputFile = "F:\\MY WORK\\CollectionPractice\\WebContent\\APCR1.pdf";

            System.out.println("inputFile:" + inputFile + ",outputFile:" + outputFile);

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(in);

            File outFile = new File(outputFile);

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

            PdfOptions options = null;

            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

when i run this code an error occur like these and i have used following jar files also.

> error:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.getPackageRelationship()Lorg/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/PackageRelationship;

jars:
[List of jar files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtF0S.png)

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`, your method doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you added external .jar file to your project?

Comment: No only above listed jars in project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have jar-versions of POI mixed up. The error indicates that the class that was loaded did not have a method that the calling class saw during compilation, so you have a different version of POI in your classpath.

See "Component Map" at https://poi.apache.org/overview.html for the different components that are included and which jars they end up, make sure you only have one of these jars in your classpath, not multiple different versions.